# How to select table cells in NxN using React ts

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a table grid component that will select the n*n matrix base on our mouse hover, I have build the layout but stuck in creating the logic for it

[image: Current Table Layout]

[image]

Expected

If I am trying to hover on to 24 cell previous cells will be selected in nxn

```
import "./Table.css";
const Table: FC<{ initialClick?: number }> = (): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>26</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>46</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>54</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>56</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Comment: it is straight forward , let's suppose `(i,j)` represents a cell, if the selected cell is `(2,4)` then you have to change the background of cells in which `i<=2` and `j<=4` . create table using  loop instead of hardcoding

Comment: here is code sample https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-platform-0rllr?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's suppose `(i,j)` represents a cell, if the selected cell is `(2,4)` then you have to change the background of cells in which `i<=2` and `j<=4`.

here is codesandbox url of sample code for `8x8` board you can easily extend it to `nxm` https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-platform-0rllr?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedCell, setSelectedCell] = useState({ row: 0, col: 0 });
  const Tile = (props) => {
    const { color, id, row, col } = props;
    return (
      <div
        id={id}
        className={`${color} tile`}
        onMouseEnter={() => {
          setSelectedCell({ row, col });
        }}
      >
        {id}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const createBoard = (n,m) => {
    let board = [];
    for (let row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
      let boardRow = [];
      for (let col = 1; col <= m; col++) {
        const color =
          row <= selectedCell.row && col <= selectedCell.col ? "black" : "";
        boardRow.push(
          <Tile
            key={`${col}${row}`}
            color={color}
            id={`${col}${row}`}
            row={row}
            col={col}
          />
        );
      }
      board.push(
        <div key={`${row}`} className="row">
          {boardRow}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return board;
  };
  return <div className="App">{createBoard(8,8)}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much shubham jha, it worked as I expected

Comment: @LalithAditya upvote or accept my answer if it answers your question.